# Search On encrypted Text in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there any best way to search the encrypted data in DB by using Node js?

I stored encrypted data in DB. How can I search the encrypted text via Code?

Example:

```
$ node encrypt.js 123 'hello my friend'
90cbf635540412a202eb46dada1fcf

$ node encrypt.js 123 'hello'
90cbf63554

$ node encrypt.js 123 ' my '
d8c3e379

$ node encrypt.js 123 'friend'
9edcf33c5540
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search on the encrypted text - that would defeat the purpose of encrypting it in the first place. As you noticed the different pieces of the string will encrypt to completely different values - this is by design or it would make your encryption much easier to crack.

What you *can* do is hash pieces of the text you want to search and store those hashes in a different table reference back to the parent.

**Table `parent` (the encrypted strings)**

```
id        string
1         xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz (encrypted 'hello my friend')
```

Then you would decompose the `string` into `word` components.

```
var words = string.split(' '); // words is an array of ['hello', 'my', 'friend']
```

Iterate over this array and compute a hash for each of the `words`, then insert those hashes into an "index" table.

**Table `words` (index word hashes to encrypted parent)**

```
id     parent_id     hash
1      1             abc (hash of "hello")
2      1             def (hash of "my")
3      1             ghi (hash of "friend")
```

At this point you would be able to compose a search query into different words, compute their hashes, and then return the `parent_id` for any matches. Note that this will only work for *complete* words - any variation will change the computed hash, so you might want to force everything to lowercase for example.

Assuming you were searching for "hello", you would compute its hash of "abc" and then run the following SQL query.

```
SELECT p.id, p.string 
FROM parent p
JOIN words w ON p.id = w.parent_id
WHERE w.hash IN ('abc')
GROUP BY p.id
```